# Samba share permissions on client not the same as server

Tags: server, permissions, mount, samba

I have two machines, one host and one client, both running Ubuntu Server 18.04. The host machine has the samba server with the following config:

```
[data]
    comment = Data Share
    path = /path/to/data
    browseable = no
    create mask = 0770
    directory mask = 0770
    force user = dataadmin
    force group = dataadmin
    write list = @data-write
    read list = @data-write @data-read
    valid users = @data-write @data-read
```

On the client machine I have the share mounted with the following in the file system table:

```
//myserver.local.lan/data        /mnt/data   cifs    username=dataadmin,password=notarealpassword,iocharset=utf8       0       0
```

When I check the file permissions with a good ol' `ls -al` on the server it shows `-rwxrwx---` which is what I was expecting, but when I check the permissions on the client it shows up as `-rwxr-xr-x`. How do I get the permissions to match on the client machine?

Note: I originally had set the permissions to 0775 on the host and recently changed them as an application requires 0770 for it to function. Not sure if this is relevant as the permissions on the client look like 0755

**Edit**

Forgot to mention what I tried so far.

- I tried chmod'ing the files on both the server and the client
- I tried setting `unix extensions` to both on and off
- I tried using `file_mode` and `dir_mode` as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384120/how-to-set-up-group-write-permissions-on-new-created-files-on-cifs-mount-point)

None of these has worked for me. After each try I either reload the smbd and nmbd services or try remounting everything. Not sure if that's enough or if I need to be doing something else on top of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried using file_mode and dir_mode as described here

The only problem with the link is a missing option since this is Linux to Linux.

If 770 is what you desire on the client give this a shot:

```
//myserver.local.lan/data        /mnt/data   cifs    username=dataadmin,password=notarealpassword,iocharset=utf8,dir_mode=0770,file_mode=0770,nounix       0       0
```

Comment: Could you explain why you set `nounix` when the environment *is* unix?